# c# infitine pooling inside a window service somehow is crashing after 2 or 3 days

Tags: c#, windows-services, task, task-parallel-library

I have a Windows Service in C# that start an Infinite Pooling for reading AWS SQS (Queues)

The code is like this:

```cs
//AWS SQS
private readonly SQSMessageBroker _sqsProcessor;
private Task _sqsTask;
private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellation;

public SyncService(Services services)
{
    _services = services;

    InitializeComponent();
    CanPauseAndContinue = true;

    // AWS SQS
    _sqsProcessor = new SQSMessageBroker(_services);
    _cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    EventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceName + " service started");

    // start sqs processor
    _sqsProcessor.Model = _model;
    _sqsProcessor.ServiceName = this.ServiceName;
    _sqsTask = _sqsProcessor.Run(_cancellation.Token);
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    _cancellation.Cancel();

    try
    {
        _sqsTask.Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SQS task was cancelled.");
    }
}
```

And my `SQSMessageBroker` class:

```cs
public class SQSMessageBroker
{
    private readonly string _sqsQueueUrl;
    private readonly IAmazonSQS _amazonSqs;

    private Services _services;

    private ConfigurationModel _model;

    public ConfigurationModel Model { set { _model = value; } }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }

    public SQSMessageBroker(Services services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }


    public async Task Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest
            {
                QueueUrl = _sqsQueueUrl
            };

            var receiveMessageResponse = await _amazonSqs.ReceiveMessageAsync(receiveMessageRequest, cancellationToken);
            if (!receiveMessageResponse.Messages.Any())
            {
                continue;
            }

            foreach (var message in receiveMessageResponse.Messages)
            {

                ... some code here

                    >>> HERE
                    * **something could be crashing here the while loop * **


            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if you see when my service starts the `infinite pooling` task starts and **it should be running forever**. The problem is that by some reason after 2 or 3 days it stops working and I guess is because something inside the while loop generates an `exception` and then the task is cancelled.

What do you recommend me to do inside the while loop? Should I added a `try catch` statement and then if an `exception` happens run again the infinite pooling task so its always running?

> I need the infinite looping to always runs even if by some reason sometimes inside the while loop something crashes.

Comment: I would say by adding try/catch and then logging the exception details and stack trace in the catch block, you can at least see the source of error. If it runs for 2 or 3 days fine, then suddenly stops, it might be related to memory leak and a gradual stack overflow, or an unexpected lack of access to a dependent resource.

Comment: Totally agree with that. I will go that way. Thanks

Comment: You should bre getting an AggregateExceptipn with the try catch you have in OnStart. So probably OutOfMemoryException or StackOverflowException.  You should add logging for that aggregate exception's content. Also would be nice to log when cancellation was actually requested, to debug this